# How store Username locally for fast calculation in database

Tags: authentication, cookies, database-design, architecture, identityserver4

I don't know, my question is weird or not, because I could not found answer yet.

I am trying to write "BLOG LIKE" website witch will have users. When I will go on Main Feed, system should show me all Posts. While getting posts from database, system should check post is mine, is post of my "friend" or post of some other user. If post is mine, system should add "Edit button in there if it is friends post system should show me some other buttons (so system should know post is mine, friends, persons who blocked me or someone else).

I will find connection with me and post authors using my username. is it my post? is creator my friend? I have blocked him or whatever it is, I will find it using my username. So when I enter to website I want get my username and have it before I will log out or close the site.
I am using IdentityServer4 so I have "User ID" witch I can get immediately and then with this "User ID"  I am searching my username in another database.

My question is where to store my username after first entering in website, to calculate everything faster without searching username in database again and again using my user ID? I thought cookies but as I have understood it is not good way.

If question is very silly, please help me to understand better way.
Sorry and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your technology stack is, but here are some suggestions:

1. Ideally you use User ID, not UserName for checking, if the username changes you will have issues
2. You can store things in the cookie but make sure to encrypt the cookie
3. It is not a bad idea to query your database for every web request, it is in fact preferable, you don't know when the last request was made, and since then the database could have changed.
4. You can cache data (e.g. username) within a single request, for example http context object, or cache and if you can't find it, then read from DB and cache it in the context object.

Comment: Thank you. I think first way is best